# Reading a line from a file into different variables using fstream

Tags: c++, ifstream, cin, getline

I wonder if there is any way to not ignore spaces when trying to assign a value to name.

I would like to keep this conditional structure* in the while loop but getting the ClientFile >> like getline and not as cin.

*I know I could use substring and find, that is not the idea.

Line example from text file:

> 1 ; Iron Man ; 10.70

Problem:
The program does not enter the loop because name is being assigned as only Iron.

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream ClientsFile("clients.txt");
    int id;
    string name;
    double money;
    char sep1;
    char sep2;

    while (ClientsFile >> id >> sep1 >> name >> sep2 >> money)
    {
        cout << "id: " << id << endl << "name: " << name << endl << "money: " << money << endl << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input operator `>>` separates on white-space. Instead you might want to use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read the semicolon separated fields.

Something like

```
std::string id_string, money_string;
while (std::getline(ClientsFile, id_string, ';') &&
       std::getline(ClientsFile, name, ';') &&
       std::getline(ClientsFile, money_string))
{
    id = std::stoi(id_string);
    money = std::stod(money_string);
    ...
}
```

Comment: That's what I needed. Thank you.